# DataFrame merging with ordered indices and different columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, join, merge

I have two pandas data-frames, which I wanted to merge. The data-frames have different columns and overlapping indices. I want to merge them, keeping the order of indices intact.

Dataframe (d1)

```
                              Dec 16 Dec 15   
Balance Sheet                     
NON-CURRENT LIABILITIES          NaN    NaN   <-- 'all Nan' row
Other Long Term Liabilities     8.37   9.30
Long Term Provisions           13.53  12.74   <-- Not present in d2
Total Non-Current Liabilities  21.90  22.04
CURRENT LIABILITIES              NaN    NaN   <-- 'all Nan' row
Trade Payables                 32.49  24.26
```

Dataframe (d2)

```
                               Dec 11 Dec 10
Balance Sheet                     
NON-CURRENT LIABILITIES           NaN    NaN
Deferred Tax Liabilities [Net]   0.00   7.40   <-- Not present in d1
Other Long Term Liabilities     14.13   0.00
Total Non-Current Liabilities   14.13   7.40
CURRENT LIABILITIES               NaN    NaN
Trade Payables                  77.35  60.40
```

I tried the following ways to merge these data-frames, but none of them worked.

```
d1.merge(d2, how='left', left_index=True,right_index=True)

d1.merge(d2, how='outer', left_index=True,right_index=True)

pd.merge_ordered(d1,d2,left_on=['Dec 16'],right_on=['Dec 11'])

pd.concat([d1.merge(d2, how='left', left_index=True,right_index=True),d1.merge(d2, how='right', left_index=True,right_index=True)]).drop_duplicates(subset='Dec 16',keep='last')
```

I am expecting the resulting dataframe to look like this

```
                              Dec 16 Dec 15 Dec 11 Dec 10
Balance Sheet                    
NON-CURRENT LIABILITIES          NaN    NaN  NaN    NaN
Deferred Tax Liabilities [Net]   NaN    NaN  0.00   7.40    <-- from d2
Other Long Term Liabilities     8.37   9.30  14.13  0.00    <-- d1+d2 merged
Long Term Provisions           13.53  12.74  NaN    NaN     <-- from d1
Total Non-Current Liabilities  21.90  22.04  14.13  7.40    <-- d1+d2 merged
CURRENT LIABILITIES              NaN    NaN  NaN    NaN
Trade Payables                 32.49  24.26  77.35  60.40
```

Note that the overall order matters (e.g all NaN rows need to be in same order), but not the order of merged indices between the 'all NaN' rows. Also the columns of d1 should come prior to d2 columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `how=outer` with `merge` and `reindex` with custom order

```
In [1424]: order_index =  ['NON-CURRENT LIABILITIES',  'Deferred Tax Liabilities [Net]',  
                           'Other Long Term Liabilities',  'Long Term Provisions',  
                           'Total Non-Current Liabilities',  'CURRENT LIABILITIES',
                           'Trade Payables']

In [1425]: df1.merge(df2,how='outer',left_index=True,right_index=True).reindex(order_index)
Out[1425]:
                                Dec 16  Dec 15  Dec 11  Dec 10
Balance Sheet
NON-CURRENT LIABILITIES            NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
Deferred Tax Liabilities [Net]     NaN     NaN    0.00     7.4
Other Long Term Liabilities       8.37    9.30   14.13     0.0
Long Term Provisions             13.53   12.74     NaN     NaN
Total Non-Current Liabilities    21.90   22.04   14.13     7.4
CURRENT LIABILITIES                NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
Trade Payables                   32.49   24.26   77.35    60.4
```

Also, `join` works

```
In [1426]: df1.join(df2, how='outer').reindex(order_index)
Out[1426]:
                                Dec 16  Dec 15  Dec 11  Dec 10
Balance Sheet
NON-CURRENT LIABILITIES            NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
Deferred Tax Liabilities [Net]     NaN     NaN    0.00     7.4
Other Long Term Liabilities       8.37    9.30   14.13     0.0
Long Term Provisions             13.53   12.74     NaN     NaN
Total Non-Current Liabilities    21.90   22.04   14.13     7.4
CURRENT LIABILITIES                NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
Trade Payables                   32.49   24.26   77.35    60.4
```

---

Details

```
In [1417]: df1
Out[1417]:
                               Dec 16  Dec 15
Balance Sheet
NON-CURRENT LIABILITIES           NaN     NaN
Other Long Term Liabilities      8.37    9.30
Long Term Provisions            13.53   12.74
Total Non-Current Liabilities   21.90   22.04
CURRENT LIABILITIES               NaN     NaN
Trade Payables                  32.49   24.26

In [1418]: df2
Out[1418]:
                                Dec 11  Dec 10
Balance Sheet
NON-CURRENT LIABILITIES            NaN     NaN
Deferred Tax Liabilities [Net]    0.00     7.4
Other Long Term Liabilities      14.13     0.0
Total Non-Current Liabilities    14.13     7.4
CURRENT LIABILITIES                NaN     NaN
Trade Payables                   77.35    60.4
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, but in both cases the indices gets sorted. The requirement is that at-least the 'all NaN' rows should remain in order.

Comment: Updated with reindex, that helps?

Comment: Thanks, yes that definitely helps. Is there a way to prepare order_index dynamically by union of d1.index and d2.index, since these names may be different and not known beforehand. Thanks a lot for all the help.

Comment: But, what will be the sort order logic, I don't see they are alphabetically?

Comment: Sort logic is that the capital letter indices (all Nan rows) will be present in both data-frames and need to create union of all indices between them.

Comment: Accepting your answer since it was most helpful. I was able to write code to get union of indices as per my requirement. Thanks